# xzzIntersect groups of child rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to get “suggested” groupings of records based off of existing data.

Table A has a composite key of `Akey+Bkey`. Table B has a primary key of `Bkey`.

`Akey` is generated from a SQL 2012 Sequence object and there is a one to many relationship between table A and table and Table B on Bkey.

The structure and sample data are listed below.

**Table A**

```
Akey  Bkey  ItemSequence
----  ----  ------------
1     1     1
1     5     2
1     7     3
2     7     1
3     2     1
3     3     2
```

**Table B**

```
Bkey  GroupValue       Data            HashString
----  ---------------  --------------  ----------
1     Ford Festiva     AIR BAG         HASH1
2     Ford Festiva     RADIATOR CAP    HASH2
3     Ford Festiva     FUEL PUMP       HASH3
4     Ford Mustang     AIR FILTER      HASH4
5     Ford Explorer    AIR FILTER      HASH5
6     Ford Edge        RADIATOR CAP    HASH2
7     Ford Edge        FUEL PUMP       HASH3
```

The query has to insert  new groups into Table A that match existing sets of Bkeys where the HASH value matches in Table B.  To depict the point I use the example of a car model.  The hash values of the items within the model of the car could match exactly ( but they might not  ).  So if all items exist within of OVER the GroupValue then I want to insert a new set of records into Table A with the values where the exact matches were found within that group.
In the sample data you can see that AKey 3 has BKeys 2 and 3 and Bkeys 6 and 7 are a match so these 2 records would be inserted into Table A and a new sequence # generated for the AKey.

Comment: What's with the `xzz`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the part about the groups and GroupValue field.

According to what I understand, you want to insert into Table A any rows from Table B that match the HashString for the Bkey of each AKey and don't already exist in Table A?

If I understand correctly: for Akey1, row TableB.Bkey 7 should be added to Table A.  Is that right?

If the logic is good, the following query should select those rows.

```
SELECT 
    a.Akey, a.Bkey, b3.* 
FROM b 
    INNER JOIN a ON a.Bkey=b.Bkey 
    INNER JOIN b b2 ON b2.HashString=b.HashString and b2.Bkey=a.Bkey
    INNER JOIN b b3 ON b3.HashString=b2.HashString AND b3.Bkey <> b.Bkey 
WHERE a.Akey=3 --Comment this line for the full matches
```